# Creating polymorphic associations has_many/has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two rails models - Shipments and Notes.
Notes is a polymorphic association with a body and status.

A shipment can have many notes. (`has_many :notes, as: :notable`)

However, I'd also like to create a has_one relationship in Shipments to show the most recent note with a status that isn't null.

I've tried a few different things but with no luck, including the code below. Anyone know how I can do this? I'm using ruby on rails 4. Please let me know if I can provide any other information.

`has_one :last_note_with_status, -> { 
  where('notes.notable_type = Shipment')
  .where('notes.status is not null')
  .order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Note'`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify which object you want to return, the most `Note` or the `Shipment`

Comment: I want to return the Shipment based on the Note.status.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need a has_one clause to achieve that. I think the best way to achieve it is to create a couple scopes on notes:

```
class Note
  scope :latest, order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
  scope :with_status, where("status is not null")
end
```

and declare a method in your shipment class:

```
class Shipment
  def latest_note_with_status
    notes.latest.with_status.first
  end
end
```

Comment: Then how would I get a collection of shipments where the note status isn't "resolved"? Would I have to loop through the collection and check them one by one?

Comment: You could do another scope for that..  `scope :note_resolved, where.not(status: "Resolved")` then tack that on to your query `notes.latest.with_status.not_resolved.first`

Comment: Just keep chaining scopes. they are very useful for these kind of things

Comment: That totally makes sense but I guess where I don't follow is, how do I implement this? Would I have to do a Shipment.all and then loop through checking each shipment.latest_note_with_status?

Comment: If you want to query all shipments including the latest note with status, thats a different thing. I thought you wanted to have a latest_note_with_status in your model.

Comment: I want to query all shipments that aren't delivered (there's a status on the shipments table that says delivered, or in transit) and out of those, I want to exclude the ones that have the last note with a note status saying "resolved" or "delivered" (the notes table also has a status column on it)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the foreign key...

```
has_one :last_note_with_status, 
  -> { where(notable_type: 'Shipment').where.not(status: nil) }, 
  class_name: 'Note',
  foreign_key: :notable_id
```

This will give you a single record.  From the sounds of what you are wanting, something like this might work:

```
  scope: :last_unresolved, joins(:notes)
     .where('notes.created_at = (SELECT MAX(notes.created_at) FROM notes WHERE notes.notable_id = shipments.id AND notes.notable_type = "Shipment")')
     .where('notes.status NOT IN (?)', ["Delivered", "Resolved"])
     .where('shipments.status NOT IN (?)', ["Delivered", "Resolved"])
     .group('shipments.id')
```

Untested, but you can try something like this

Comment: I tried that as well, however when I use it in my scope:
`scope :last_status_is_not_in, -> () {
    statuses = ["delivered", "resolved"]
    where("last_note_with_status.item_status not in (?)", statuses)
  }`

I get the following error.
`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "last_note_with_status" LINE 1: ...ry_datetime >= '2017-03-28 20:37:14.182266') AND (last_note_... ^`

Comment: last_note_with_status is not a table...  What the above has_one relationship will give you is the ability to call "last_not_with_status" on your object...  `Shipment.last.last_note_with_status` ... that will return a single note record...  I am not sure that creating this relationship is truly what you want...

Comment: If I run the scope on Shipment, shouldn't I get a collection back? ex if I have a scope `scope :late, -> () {where("UPPER(status) != 'DELIVERED')}` Then shouldn't I be able to do something like `Shipment.late.last_status_is_not_in` and it should return a collection of shipments that don't have a status 'Delivered' on the shipments table and have the last note attached that says 'resolved' or 'delivered'? Thanks for your help!